# Quinte (de toux)

Tags: expressions, étymologie, santé-et-médecine

Tout le monde connait l'expression

> Il a une quinte de toux.

Mais d'où provient cette expression, quel est le rapport entre quinte et toux ?

Par ailleurs, on trouve le mot quinte dans la [8ème](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/quinte) édition du dictionnaire de l'Académie mais pas dans la [9ème](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/quinte) !!!

Comment: Au sujet du dictionnaire de l'Académie, _que_ n'est pas non plus disponible avec cette interface.  [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_l%27Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise#Tomes_parus) indique que le volume correspondant est paru en 2011 ; je ne suis pas sûr que le site est à jour.

Comment: @Unfrancophone En effet, la version sur le site [ne va que jusqu'à *plébéien*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/dictionnaires/anciens/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Plusieurs](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quinte) [références](http://college.saintebarbe.pagespro-orange.fr/rome/etymolog.htm) semblent indiquer que cela fait référence à la fréquence à laquelle interviennent les accès de toux, à savoir toutes les cinq heures, dans le cas d'une coqueluche.

Comment: Intéressant. C'est également indiqué ici : http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/quinte